# Register php Rest and APP not send credentials

Tags: php, android, rest

I have built a REST service with php from a model I found, but after trying and trying I cannot get any result.

The app is builded with no errors. But when I try to test in my device it doesn't work.
I can't find any error.

Here is the code I wrote, I will appreciate if anyone could help me.

> **Translate Note:**
>
> Correo = email
> Contrasena = password
> Nombre = name
> Encriptada = encrypted
>
> Changed Salt name into claveApi

**Logcat**

```
02-16 13:01:56.107 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-16 13:01:56.308 27336-29449/com.amg_eservices.mywisen I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
02-16 13:01:56.318 27336-29449/com.amg_eservices.mywisen I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
02-16 13:01:56.548 27336-29449/com.amg_eservices.mywisen I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <html><head> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/System.err:     at com.amg_eservices.mywisen.RegisterandLogin.RegistrationActivity$3.onResponse(RegistrationActivity.java:103)
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/System.err:     at com.amg_eservices.mywisen.RegisterandLogin.RegistrationActivity$3.onResponse(RegistrationActivity.java:96)
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:67)
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
02-16 13:01:56.708 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
02-16 13:02:26.137 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{2f1aeb60 token=android.os.BinderProxy@3b2fb0be {com.amg_eservices.mywisen/com.amg_eservices.mywisen.RegisterandLogin.RegistrationActivity}} show : true
02-16 13:02:27.178 27336-27336/com.amg_eservices.mywisen W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection`
```

**MySQL DB**

With “usuarios” table

```
idUsuario | nombre | contrasena | claveApi | correo
```

**Structure:**

PHP

Public access root to php rest

http://wi-sen.esy.es/v1.2

I have in hostinger a subdirectory called v1.2

**Inside:**

- DB_Function.php
- db_Connect.php
- db_config.php
- index.php

**In APP**

- AppController
- AppURLs
- LoginActivity
- MainActivity
- RegistrationActivity
- Session
- SplashScreenActivity

**AppController**

```java
package com.amg_eservices.mywisen.RegisterandLogin;
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

 */
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();
    private static AppController mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }

}
```

**AppURLs**

```java
package com.amg_eservices.mywisen.RegisterandLogin;

public class AppURLs {
    public static String URL = "http://wi-sen.esy.es/v1.2";
}
```

**LoginActivity**

```java
package com.amg_eservices.mywisen.RegisterandLogin;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * A login screen that offers login via email/password.
 */
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button registrationButton, loginButton;
    private EditText email_to_login, password_to_login;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Session session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
        session = new Session(LoginActivity.this);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        registrationButton = (Button)     findViewById(R.id.registration_button);
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signin_button);
        email_to_login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_to_login);
        password_to_login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_to_login);


        registrationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegistrationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = email_to_login.getText().toString();
                String password = password_to_login.getText().toString();

                if (email.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0) {
                    checkLogin(email, password);
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(v, "Please enter the credentials!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppURLs.URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    String userId = jObj.getString("user_id");

                    if (userId != null) {
                        session.setLogin(true);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Post params to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "login");
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to  queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}`
```

**MainActivity**

```java
package com.amg_eservices.mywisen.RegisterandLogin;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnLogout;
    private Session session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
        session = new Session(MainActivity.this);

        if (!session.getLoggedIn()) {
            logoutUser();
        }

        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logoutUser();
            }
        });
    }


    private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**RegistrationActivity**

```java
package com.amg_eservices.mywisen.RegisterandLogin;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvLogin;
    private EditText fullName, email_to_register, password_to_register;
    private Button registerButton;
    private Session session;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        session = new Session(RegistrationActivity.this);

        if (session.getLoggedIn()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_button);
        fullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fullname_register);
        email_to_register = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_register);
        password_to_register = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_register);
        tvLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_signin);

        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String nombre = fullName.getText().toString();
                String correo = email_to_register.getText().toString();
                String contrasena = password_to_register.getText().toString();

                if (!nombre.isEmpty() && !correo.isEmpty() && !contrasena.isEmpty()) {
                    registerUser(nombre, correo, contrasena);
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(v, "Porfavor introduzca las credenciales!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

        tvLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this,
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void registerUser(final String nombre, final String correo,
                              final String contrasena) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        pDialog.setMessage("Registrando ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppURLs.URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                RegistrationActivity.this,
                                LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "registro");
                params.put("nombre", nombre);
                params.put("correo", correo);
                params.put("contrasena", contrasena);

                return params;
            }

        };

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**Session**

```java
package com.amg_eservices.mywisen.RegisterandLogin;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;


public class Session {
    private SharedPreferences sp;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor;

    public Session(Context context) {
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    }

    public boolean setLogin(boolean status) {
        spEditor = sp.edit();
        spEditor.putBoolean("is_logged_in", status);
        spEditor.commit();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean getLoggedIn() {
        return sp.getBoolean("is_logged_in", false);
    }
}
```

**SplashScreenActivity**

It is just a simple jump screen to the login screen. >Not important

#### PHP files

**Index.php**

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
/**
 * File to handle all API requests
 * Accepts GET and POST
 * 
 * Each request will be identified by TAG
 * Response will be JSON data

  /**
 * check for POST request 
 */
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    // get tag
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];

    // include DB_function
    require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    // response Array
    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "error" => FALSE);

    // checking tag
    if ($tag == 'login') {
        // Request type is check Login
        $correo = $_POST['correo'];
        $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];

        // check for user
        $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($correo, $contrasena);
        if ($user != false) {
            // user found
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["idUsuario"] = $user["idUsuario"];
            $response["user"]["nombre"] = $user["nombre"];
            $response["user"]["correo"] = $user["correo"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user not found
            // echo json with error = 1
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "correo incorrecto o contraseña incorrecta!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else if ($tag == 'registro') {
        // Request type is Register new user
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $correo = $_POST['correo'];
        $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];

        // check if user is already existed
        if ($db->isUserExisted($correo)) {
            // user is already existed - error response
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Usuario ya existente";
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // store user
            $user = $db->storeUser($nombre, $correo, $contrasena);
            if ($user) {
                // user stored successfully
                $response["error"] = FALSE;
                $response["uid"] = $user["idUsuario"];
                $response["user"]["nombre"] = $user["nombre"];
                $response["user"]["correo"] = $user["correo"];
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = TRUE;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Ha ocurrido un error en el registro";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Etiqueta desconocida, debe seleccionar o login o registro";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    ?><html><head>
        <title>Inicializando Android | API</title>
</head>
<body style="background:#2c3e50;">
        <div style="margin:0 auto; margin-top:200px;width:60%;">
                <img src="logo_api.png" alt="Iniciando Android">
        </div>

</body></html><?php
}
?>
```

**DB_Function.php**

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
class DB_Functions {

    private $db;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $this->db = new DB_Connect();
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        
    }

    /**
     * Store user details
     */
    public function storeUser($nombre, $correo, $contrasena) {
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($contrasena);
        $contrasena = $hash["encriptada"]; // encrypted password
        $claveApi = $hash["claveApi"]; // salt
        $resultado = mysqli_query($this->db->con,"INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre, correo, contrasena, claveApi) VALUES('$nombre', '$correo', '$contrasena', '$claveApi')") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
        // check for result
        if ($resultado) {
            // gettig the details
            $uid = mysqli_insert_id($this->db->con); // last inserted id
            $resultado = mysqli_query($this->db->con,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE idUsuario = $uid");
            // return details
     
            return mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get user by email and password
     */
    public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($correo, $contrasena) {
        $resultado = mysqli_query($this->db->con,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = '$correo'") or die(mysqli_connect_error());
        // check for result 
        $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
            $claveApi = $resultado['claveApi'];
            $contrasena = $resultado['contrasena'];
            $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($claveApi, $contrasena);
            // check for password
            if ($contrasena == $hash) {
                return $resultado;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check user is existed or not
     */
    public function isUserExisted($correo) {
        $resultado = mysqli_query($this->db->con,"SELECT correo from usuarios WHERE correo = '$correo'");
        $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            // user exist
            return true;
        } else {
            // user not exist
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypting password
     * @param password
     * returns salt and encrypted password
     */
    public function hashSSHA($contrasena) {

        $claveApi = sha1(rand());
        $claveApi = substr($claveApi, 0, 10);
        $encriptada = base64_encode(sha1($contrasena . $claveApi, true) . $claveApi);
        $hash = array("claveApi" => $claveApi, "encriptada" => $encriptada);
        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypting password
     * @param salt, password
     * returns hash string
     */
    public function checkhashSSHA($claveApi, $contrasena) {

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($contrasena . $claveApi, true) . $claveApi);

        return $hash;
    }

}

?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error:

```
 org.json.JSONException: Value <html><head> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Indicates that you open the wrong url or the `else` part of your index.php. You server returns a standard html webpage when you expect to receive JSON content.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jörn Buitink. Then in APPUrls.java file I would have to write ("wi-sen.esy.es/v1.2/index.php";) ? How can I solve it, could you write down exemple? Thanks in adavance for your help, I am not so good with codding. – Oscar C.